# Edit pdf using python/R

Tags: python, r, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a wedding card pdf file with 5 images. I want to add a guest name at a specific location on the first page of the pdf. Using this I want to generate different pdf’s for different guests.

The names are available in an excel. Is there a way to go about this in R/Python?

Comment: you should explore quarto and qmd files

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend doing this in Python.

Save a photo of your wedding card, leaving a blank spot for the guest name. Then modify this code:

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

wedding_guest = input("Enter name of wedding guest: ")
pdf_filename = f"{wedding_guest}_wedding_invite.pdf"

image = "FILENAME" # This should be the screenshot of the wedding invite

height_page = 720 # Modify so that it is the same size of the image
width_page = 1270

c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_filename, pagesize=(width_page,height_page))

def add_text(text, x, y, size=12): # You can change font and color for text here
    c.setFillColorRGB(255, 255, 255)
    c.setFont("Helvetica", size)
    c.drawString(x, y, text)

# Production of PDF
c.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width=width_page,height=height_page,mask=None)

add_text(wedding_guest, X-COORDINATE, Y-COORDINATE, SIZE(Default 12))

c.save
```

Then if you want to loop through a list of guests you can implement this :)

Happy wedding <3